# Manage new users data in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

How and when should I push user data to Firebase Realtime Database after a new user registers (multi-provider) using the Firebase UI.

I was able to push user data to the user's node using `GOOGLE_PROVIDER` but the app crashes when I sign in with `EMAIL_PROVIDER`. 
User class

```
public class User {
private String name;
private String email;
private String phone;
private String photo;

public User() {

}

public User(String name, String email, String phone, String photo) {
    setName(name);
    setEmail(email);
    setPhone(phone);
    setPhoto(photo);//when arg ==null Photo = MyUrls.NEWUSERIMG 
    }
    ...
}

...

 private void onSignedInInitiliaze() {
        //Todo  Email Provider !
    String name = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName();
    String email = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
    String phone = "";//// TODO 
    String photo = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getPhotoUrl().toString();
    User currentUser = new User(name, email, phone, photo);
    userRef.setValue(currentUser);
}
```

Comment: Please post the logcat showing the Exception that is thrown when the application crashes

Comment: fixed by replacing String class with object class